# How to address container for logging using docker-compose

Tags: logging, docker, docker-compose, fluentd

A container described in `docker-compose.yml` uses logging extension to send log to a fluentd container.

```
version: "2"

services:

  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:v0.14.8
    container_name: fluentd

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.5
    container_name: nginx
    links:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        fluentd-address: fluentd:24224
```

But this configuration does not work, as the `fluentd-address` is seen externally by the host (aka the host) and not from within the nginx container.

So it requires a way to know the IP address of container outside the container but in a compatible way for docker-compose, any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest docker-compose it wont work on links, you need to use docker networks.

And actually you can omit the `fluentd-address` because fluentd log driver autodiscover for anyting that listening on 24224 in that case

```
version: "2"
services:
  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:v0.14.8
    container_name: fluentd
    networks:
      - nw-01

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.5
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - nw-01
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
networks:
  nw-01:
    external: true
```